# Attempting to set a heroku buildpack before deploying project

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am working on deploying my first app to heroku. However, I am hitting a wall in deployment. When I try to deploy the most basic Hello World app to Heroku I recieve the following error message:

> !     No default language could be detected for this app.
>               HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
>               See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

So, according to the Heroku docs I need to set the buildpack for my application, so I try the following, and get the following error

[image]

Just to note, I am using  node for my command prompt and I have installed the heroku CLI on node using npm. I am not familiar with -a or --app App but when I try to put those somewhere within the set buildpacks command, I am not having any luck.

any help would be much appreciated, I've spent the last four hours working on this with no success.

Comment: You put `--app name-of-your-app`. The name is the one from the Heroku console at https://dashboard.heroku.com/.

Comment: So would the command look like:

 --app helloworldbydavidreke heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs

I just gave that a try and it didn't work, so I'm suspecting I'm still not getting it right

Comment: No. The `--app` part goes on the end.